# Improve algorithm for finding URLs in a body of text - obj-c

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, url, nsrange

I'm trying to come up with an algorithm to find URLs in a body of text. I currently have the following code (this was my sit down and hack it out code, and I know there has to be a better way):

```
    statusText.text = @"http://google.com http://www.apple.com www.joshholat.com";

NSMutableArray *urlLocations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSRange currentLocation = NSMakeRange(0, statusText.text.length);
for (int x = 0; x < statusText.text.length; x++) {
    currentLocation = [[statusText.text substringFromIndex:(x + currentLocation.location)] rangeOfString:@"http://"];
    if (currentLocation.location > statusText.text.length) break;
    [urlLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(currentLocation.location + x)]];
}
currentLocation = NSMakeRange(0, statusText.text.length);
for (int x = 0; x < statusText.text.length; x++) {
    currentLocation = [[statusText.text substringFromIndex:(x + currentLocation.location)] rangeOfString:@"http://www."];
    if (currentLocation.location > statusText.text.length) break;
    [urlLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(currentLocation.location + x)]];
}
currentLocation = NSMakeRange(0, statusText.text.length);
for (int x = 0; x < statusText.text.length; x++) {
    currentLocation = [[statusText.text substringFromIndex:(x + currentLocation.location)] rangeOfString:@" www." options:NSLiteralSearch];
    if (currentLocation.location > statusText.text.length) break;
    [urlLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(currentLocation.location + 1 + x)]];
}

//Get rid of any duplicate locations
NSSet *uniqueElements = [NSSet setWithArray:urlLocations];
[urlLocations release];
NSArray *finalURLLocations = [[NSArray alloc] init];
finalURLLocations = [uniqueElements allObjects];

//Parse out the URLs of each of the locations
for (int x = 0; x < [finalURLLocations count]; x++) {
    NSRange temp = [[statusText.text substringFromIndex:[[finalURLLocations objectAtIndex:x] intValue]] rangeOfString:@" "];
    int length = temp.location + [[finalURLLocations objectAtIndex:x] intValue];
    if (temp.location > statusText.text.length) length = statusText.text.length;
    length = length - [[finalURLLocations objectAtIndex:x] intValue];
    NSLog(@"URL: %@", [statusText.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange([[finalURLLocations objectAtIndex:x] intValue], length)]);
}
```

I feel like it could be improved via the usage of regular expressions or something. Any help in improving this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you target iOS 4.0+, you should let Apple do the work for you and use the built-in data detectors. Create an instance of `NSDataDetector` with the `NSTextCheckingTypeLink` option and run it over your string. The [documentation for NSDataDetector](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has some good examples on the usage of the class.

If you don't/can't use data detectors for any reason, John Gruber has posted a good regex pattern for detecting URLs a few months ago: http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls

Comment: I came in here to post that exact regex link.

Comment: NSDataDetector was exactly what I was looking for, thanks a ton for that! I was able to get my algorithm down to like 10 lines of code. Didn't even know it existed.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a follow up, here's what my code has been changed to:

```
    statusText.text = @"http://google.com http://www.apple.com www.joshholat.com hey there google.com";

NSError *error = NULL;
NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:&error];

NSArray *matches = [detector matchesInString:statusText.text
                                     options:0
                                       range:NSMakeRange(0, statusText.text.length)];

for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypeLink) {
        NSLog(@"URL: %@", [[match URL] absoluteURL]);
    }
}
```